# Задать диапазон свойства

Tags: c#

Есть свойство `public int Time { get; set; },`, которое используется в конструкторе

```
public Person(string name, int time)
{
    Name = name;
    Time = time;
}
```

Я хочу задать значение этого свойства через консоль `firstPerson.Time = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` Возможно ли задать допустимые значения для Time, чтобы при вводе чисел за пределами диапазона, появлялось сообщение об этом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Person firstPerson = new Person { Name = "First", Time = 1 };

bool isSuccess = false;
while (!isSuccess)
{
    try
    {
        int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (n > 0 && n < 100) // требуемое условие
        {
            firstPerson.Time = n;
            isSuccess = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введенное число не удовлетворяет критериям.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если значение вводится с консоли, разумно использовать `TryParse` вместо `Parse` и не ловить исключение.

Comment: @VladD, а у автосвойств нельзя ведь сеттеры самому имплементировать?

Comment: @Grundy: Нет, но можно переделать в неавтосвойство.

Comment: @VladD, но тогда ведь и приватное поле самому надо добавлять?

Comment: @Grundy: Угу. Но это одна строчка кода :)

Comment: @Vlad да, но `TryParse` не покажет какое это было исключение - System.FormatException или System.OverflowException. Возможно, в этом случае будет лучше их различать.

Comment: @Romario: Ого! :) Ну да, для такого случая простым `TryParse` не обойтись.

Comment: @Romario Спасибо. Вопрос, возможно ли сделать эту конструкцию более универсальной, чтобы для каждого объекта не прописывать ее?

Comment: @cruim Все зависит от того как вы видите логику работы с вашими классами. Можно реализовать предложенный тут вариант с проверкой в сеттере, либо убрать сеттер у автосвойства и сделать установку значений отдельным методом, либо в конструкторе проверять при создании объекта.